# What would prevent jobs in a queue from processing? [PHP / Laravel 5]

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, queue

I have a queue I set up in Laravel 5 to delete companies and associated records.  Each time this happens, a lot of work happens on the back-end, so queues are my best option.

I set up my `config/queue.php` file along with my `.env` file so that the `database` driver will be used.  I am using the `Queue::pushOn` method to push jobs onto a queue called `company_deletions`.  Ex.

```
Queue::pushOn('company_deletions', new CompanyDelete($id));
```

Where `CompanyDelete` is a command created with `php artisan command:make CompanyDelete --queued`

I have tried to get my queue to process using the following commands:

```
php artisan queue:work
php artisan queue:work company_deletions
php artisan queue:listen
php artisan queue:listen company_deletions
php artisan queue:work database
php artisan queue:listen database
```

Sometimes when looking at the output of the above commands, I get the following error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]  
No connector for []
```

Even when I don't get an error I cannot get it to actually process the jobs for some reason.  When I look in my `jobs` table, I can see the job on the queue, however the `attempts` column shows 0, `reserved` shows 0 and `reserved_at` is null.  Am I missing some steps?  I have looked over the documentation several times and cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.  I don't see anything in the laravel error logs either.  What would prevent these jobs from being processed once they are in the `jobs` database?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should expose your `config/queue.php`

Comment: Check out the logs, see if you have any errors or so...

Comment: If laravel is failing to process it can log and It might help you to debug. More -https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#failed-jobs

Comment: Hard to debug this Issue  without  logs

Answer (score 1):

i run into a smiliar issue because i dont add the jobs in the default queue..

```
        $job = (new EmailJob(
            $this->a,
            $this->b,
            $this->c,
            $this->d,
            $e
        ))->onQueue('emails');
```

then i have to listen to the specific queue:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=emails
```

in your case it would be

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=company_deletions
```